# Npm module "grunt-sass" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, google-api-nodejs-client, grunt-sass-lint

I am using windows 10. Have installed npm version 5.6.0,node v8.10.0 and Python 2.7.

Getting **grunt-sass is not installed** even after installing npm using the command "npm install".
After that I installed grunt using command:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Also, sometimes get an error like

> "**Node Sass does not yet support your current environment**: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime"

Any help will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 8):

1. In your project folder where `package.json` exists, run:

   ```
   npm install
   ```
2. However, if the `grunt-sass` does not exist in your `package.json`, run:

   ```
   npm install grunt-sass
   ```
3. If you want it to be saved for future `npm install`, run:

   ```
   npm install grunt-sass --save
   ```

Comment: I have tried all but didn't succeed. Is it something related to version of grunt-sass and installed version of nodejs.? Grunt-sass version in package.json  is 1.0.0

Comment: can you try to do this? ```npm rebuild grunt-sass --force```